# Categorize Traffic with Specific (non-UTM) Parameter as Email Traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have traffic coming from Salesloft emails sent by sales reps that gets bounced off a subdomain and then has a `sbrc` parameter appended to the URL. I'd like to ensure that this traffic gets counted by Google Analytics as coming from Email, whereas it's currently falling under the "Direct" bucket. Ideally, users would also be appending utm parameters to their links, but this isn't happening consistently.

I tried creating a filter to search and replace the following regex `(?:^|\?|&)(sbrc=[^&]*&?)` with `?utm_medium=email&utm_source=salesloft` in the Request URI. This changed the displayed URL when looking at my realtime traffic, but did not change how GA categorized the channel of the traffic (still direct).

I then tried editing the default channel groupings for Email to be the system categorized OR Landing Page URL contains "sbrc" and dragged Email to the first channel grouping at the top. This doesn't seem to have done anything at all.

How can I make GA recognize this custom parameter as being attributable to the Email channel?

Answer (score 0):

You could use advanced filters to solve this task. The [Advanced filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en) lets you construct Fields for reporting from one or two existing Fields.

In your case, advanced filters let you assign values to campaign source and campaign medium, based on the content of the request URL. This is a sample setup for the source field, and you need a second similar filter for medium as well:

[image]

Comment: Would this apply retroactively or only going forward?

Comment: Filters are applied to incoming traffic. No retroactive changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, users would also be appending utm parameters to their links,
>   but this isn't happening consistently.

If they add their own and use a utm_medium other then utm_medium=Email, then it will not be defined as being in the default Email channel.

Filters are not retroactive.
Filters also run *after* data has already been processed by Google, to only change how it displays in the reports as it gets sent back into the GA reports.

A Search and Replace Filter applied to the RequestURI for
`?utm_medium=email&utm_source=salesloft` is not going to have the result you want.
It will change the appearance of the RequestURI in reports, not actually change how that traffic is attributed.

Changes to the default Channel grouping are not retroactive, it should have affect going forward though.

To see the changes in historical data for the Channels, you would do best to create a custom Channel grouping at the View level, this can then be applied retroactively to the historic data.

Comment: In both of my test cases, I tried implementing the solution, then fired up a new incognito window and visited the site with a ?sbrc=something parameter to see how the realtime traffic was attributed. In both cases, it still was attributed as direct.

Comment: If you create a custom channel group at the View level by copying the default Channel Group (that you edited), and you select the custom Channel Group when you go to the Acquisition report, the custom Channel Group should show retroactively. Keep in mind though you are not changing the actual source/medium and even filters are not going to change the visitor's actual source/medium which is tied to their cookies, it will simply appear differently in the GA report. You have to also then consider what affect that may have on goal attribution and similar if they are later a return visitor.

Comment: If you are using Google Tag Manager, you can add utm parameters via GTM, which will then see them attributed to the source/medium/campaign that you configure it to assign them. It gets done before the landing page hit gets sent to the GA servers for processing, which means they are cookied correctly, and attribution works as it expected, rather than just having filters altering how data is displayed in the GA reports. 
https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/how-to-alter-your-campaign-values-using-google-tag-manager/